# Is $\mathbb{P}[\{x\}]$ always zero for general probability measures?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a real-valued random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ with a cumulative distribution function $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x]$. Can we conclude from some measure theoretic property that $\mathbb{P}[X \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[X < x]$? The measure zero of singleton points is certainly true for many well-known measures, but can we conclude that in general, subtracting a finite number of points from $(-\infty, x]$ does not change the probability of $(-\infty, x]$?

I'm asking this because my reading material hasn't explicitly taken care of this, and from other courses I know that $\mathbb{P}[-x \leq X \leq x] = F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$, but arguing only with the general properties of probability measures I know of, yields $\mathbb{P}[-x \leq X \leq x] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x] - \mathbb{P}[X < -x]$, where the RHS would simplify to include only the CDF of $X$, if the finite difference of points doesn't matter.

Comment: You can have a discrete real-valued random variable, e.g., flipping a coin and assigning 0 and 1 to its different sides. Than $\mathbb P[x<1] = 0.5$ but $\mathbb P[x\leq 1] = 1$

Comment: The extra condition needed to guarantee this would be that the CDF must be *continuous*.  If the CDF is not necessarily continuous we can of course not say anything about the property you ask about.

Comment: @JMoravitz Is right-continuity enough to guarantee the equality? I.e. if $x_n\downarrow x \in \mathbb{R}$, then also $F_X(x_n)\downarrow F_X(x)$.

Comment: No, right continuity still allows jumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the measure to be continuous so it has no atoms. It’s not a general feature of all measures.

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Continuous_distribution
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)